# is there any way to close react-native-share programmatically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-share

I want to close `share.open()` when the user is inactive for a certain time. Something like the opposite of `share.open()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this package didn't have this feature!
If you use `Share` from `react-native` you can use `dismissedAction` for iOS only!!
[see this!](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/share#share)